# Creating the temp table to insert the value in the sorting order. It is working fine in SQL Server 2008 but not in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

My exact requirement is: I have an `Employee` table which is not in ordered way, so I want to order it by NM first of all and insert a new row @ the beginning of the table.

```
Insert into #temptable(ID, name, place,Address) 
   Select 
       ID, name, place, Address 
   from 
       Employee 
   order by 
       NM 

Select 
    0 as ID,
    'Select Employee' as NM,
    'No place' as place,
    'No address' as Address

Union All

Select 
    w.ID, w.NM, w.Place, w.Address 
from 
    #temptable w
```

I want the second part of union query to be ordered by NM.
The above appproach is not giving me the result in order

Suggest me any alternative way of doing this, since this not not working in SQL Server 2012

Comment: **Define** "not working" - do you get an error - if so ***what*** error?? Do you not get any results at all? Do you get results, but not ordered??

Comment: Select 
    0 as ID,
    'Select Employee' as NM,
    'No place' as place,
    'No address' as Address 
Union All
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    (Select 
        w.ID,
        w.NM,
        w.Place,
        w.Address 
    FROM 
        #temptable w 
    ORDER BY 
        w.NM) t
I tried out this query, it is throwing "The Order by Clause is ivalid in views,inline functions, suqueries. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Just because you insert them in order, does not mean that they will come out in order. Without an `ORDER BY` clause, the server can (and will) return a `SELECT` to you in what ever order was most efficient for processing.

Solution:
If you put an `ORDER BY` on your query, you will get what you want:

```
Select 
    0 as ID,
    'Select Employee' as NM,
    'No place' as place,
    'No address' as Address 
Union All
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    (Select 
        w.ID,
        w.NM,
        w.Place,
        w.Address 
    FROM 
        #temptable w 
    ORDER BY 
        w.NM) t
```

Comment: My exact requirement is, I have a Employee table which is not in ordered way,

Comment: The only way to ensure that your result set is returned in a specific order, is to use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: My exact requirement is, I have a Employee table which is not in ordered way, So i want to order it by NM first of all and insert a new row @ the beginning of the table.
Insert into #temptable(ID,name,place,Address) 
Select ID,name,place,Address from Employee order by NM 

Select 0 as ID,'Select Employee' as NM,'No place' as place,'No address' as Address
Union All
Select w.ID,w.NM,w.Place,w.Address from #temptable  w

Im expecting the result 
NM
Select Employee
Ab
bc
cd

Comment: You cannot think of a database table as an excel sheet. Relational databases are based on set theory wherein a set has no order. As such, the actual table has no concept of order, so the only way to ensure that your result set has the order that you want is to use an `ORDER BY` clause. The fact that `SQL2008` returned the result set in the order that you inserted it is merely coincidental.

Comment: The above query will apply the order by clause for overall result. Is there a way where i can apply order by clause for only second query of Union All????

Comment: I tried it out. as per the above query, It is throwing the error'The ORDER BY clause is invalid in view,inline functions, subqueries' please please help me out